# How to include a HTML in JSP at runtime?

Tags: html, jsp

I need to include html or image in a JSP at runtime. I will come to know about the jsp filename at the time of runtime. So I can't able to make the change for a JSP include.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you somehow send the name of the html page or image in query string?

Comment: Yes.. I have keyword to find whether i am going to include a html or image. Can we do this without affecting the page layout?

Comment: Just use EL in `<jsp:include>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by runtime? I have done something maybe similar. In the controller I do. `model.addAttribute("jspContent", "test.jsp")`

And then in the containing jsp file :

`<jsp:include page="${jspContent}" ></jsp:include>`

Edit:
Read your comment. I guess then it depends on what other technologies you are using. You could add the name to be included to the session and then read it in the Controller that is receiving the redirect. Adding it to the model and clearing from session. Or if you happen to use Spring I just yesterday got to know about this: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes

Edit2:
I meant something like this, I am not entirely sure if it's suitable, but it's an idea :)
In the controller that is redirecting you do something like this:

```
session.setAttribute("jspContentFromRedirect", "test.jsp");
servletResponse.sendRedirect(urlToRedirectTo);
```

And then in the receiving Controller:

```
String jspContent = session.getAttribute("jspContentFromRedirect");
if(jspContent != null){
    model.addAttribute("jspContent", jspContent);
    session.setAttribute("jspContentFromRedirect", null);
    }
```

Something like this

Comment: I can include the jspcontent in the controller as per your suggestion. But my question is about jsp file. Basically its redirect function, where i will redirect to URL(in the controller) based on the keyword searched. So there is no way i will come to about the jsp file in advance before redirecting. I can't make any changes in the jsp file of redirecting URL. Hope this clears.

Comment: Hi,                                                                    Thanks for helping me. Please explain me what do you mention by "Adding it to the model and clearing from session". Is this where i need to inlcude the content in the redirected URL?